# How about updates for Visual Studio Web application templates?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

I created a new project in `Visual Studio 2019 Community` using the **ASP.NET Core Web Application** template
[image]
and selecting **ASP.NET Core 5.0** and **ASP.NET Core with React.js**
[image]

After the project was created, I switched to the `ClientApp`folder and executed `npm update`. After that, `npm outdated` gives me:

```
Package                  Current   Wanted  Latest  Location
cross-env                  5.2.1    5.2.1   7.0.2  webapplication1
eslint                     6.8.0    6.8.0  7.14.0  webapplication1
eslint-config-react-app    5.2.1    5.2.1   6.0.0  webapplication1
eslint-plugin-flowtype     4.7.0    4.7.0   5.2.0  webapplication1
merge                      1.2.1    1.2.1   2.1.0  webapplication1
react                    16.14.0  16.14.0  17.0.1  webapplication1
react-dom                16.14.0  16.14.0  17.0.1  webapplication1
react-scripts              3.4.4    3.4.4   4.0.0  webapplication1
rimraf                     2.7.1    2.7.1   3.0.2  webapplication1
typescript                 3.9.7    3.9.7   4.1.2  webapplication1
```

Comparing wanted and latest version it seems like the templates are outdated. Are there any updates for the official templates or do I have to check manually which packages can be upgraded without breaking things?

Answer (score 0):

UI world is extremely dynamic. So I'd say it's a fact that UI packages will get updates often and MS will never be able to keep this "Zoo" up to date.

In my production experience - I usually setup UI app template myself - using webpack, typescript etc, depending on customer needs. And using SPA configuration in Asp.NET Core it's easy to make any app build within general pipe. But it's only for cases when I need it to be part of ASP.NET Core Web App. From my point of view, however, it's more correct to host SPA stuff separately from Asp.NET Core backend.

Talking about ASP.NET Core Web App template from MS (which was mentioned) - for UI it's based on create-react-app (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). You can check that in "package.json" searching for react-scripts. You can start upgrading from this entry point. And then - check what's left and upgrade the rest if needed.

p.s. By the way, some time ago MS tried to keep up to date Windows based docker image with NodeJS installed. But they ended up this support as well because of NodeJS frequent updates and versions list.